# Why does max-width behave differently than width when using margin auto to center items?

Tags: css

Using `max-width` instead of `width` for images makes sense to avoid upsampling the images, but why does this make a difference when using:

```
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: what is your goal ? max-width will make the image fill the whole container (also depends on how much height is available), so it will look different

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display at the center of your container you need `display:block`, so the code should be:

```css
max-width: 800px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

The `max-width` is used to fill that required width.